# How do I reverse this animation? Swift 3

Tags: swift, animation

This is the animation that I am currently using and I am wondering how I would reverse the code to make the animation right to left?

```
func leftToRightAnimation(duration: TimeInterval = 0.5, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil)  {

    // Create a CATransition object
    let leftToRightTransition = CATransition()

    // Set its callback delegate to the completionDelegate that was provided
    if let delegate: CAAnimationDelegate = completionDelegate as! CAAnimationDelegate? {
        leftToRightTransition.delegate = delegate
    }

    leftToRightTransition.type = kCATransitionPush
    leftToRightTransition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    leftToRightTransition.duration = duration
    leftToRightTransition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    leftToRightTransition.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved

    // Add the animation to the View's layer
    self.layer.add(leftToRightTransition, forKey: "leftToRightTransition")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
 leftToRightTransition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
```